# Pass a value from InputForm to MainForm at load

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a MainForm and an InputForm.
At MainForm load i want to open InputForm and there the user can set int piece and bool help, and i want to pass it to the MainForm to further use.

MainForm:

```
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {

    public int piece;
    public bool help;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (InputForm form = new InputForm())
        {
            if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                help = form.help;
                piece = form.piece;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Internal error");
            }
       }
   }
```

InputForm:

```
public partial class InputForm : Form
{
    public int piece;
    public bool help;

    public InputForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InputForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 132; i += 2)
        {
            comboBox.Items.Add($"{i} something");
        }
    }

    private void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        help = checkBox.Checked;
        piece = int.Parse(comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0, 2));
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

For some reason i always get that `MessageBox.Show("Internal error");`
What should i do? Can i directly pass those value to MainForm?

Comment: Set `ButtonStart.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;` in your input form (Initialize). Please let me know if this works,

Comment: Select ButtonStart in the designer, set its DialogResult property to OK.  Delete the Close() call.  Now the ShowDialog() call in the parent form has the expected return value, it used to be DialogResult.Cancel.

Comment: Thanks it worked! One question please. It would be better to use public static int piece; in MainForm and then at InputForm: MainForm.peice = something?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `Form.Close()` method on a `Form` shown with the `Form.ShowDialog()` method then the `DialogResult` will be a `Close`.

You should modify your if statement like so...

```
if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
```

Comment: Thanks, now i understand what was the problem. I rather set ButtonStart DialogResult property to OK and removed the Close at the button's click event.